# Are there any LEGO "MacGyvering kits" for the on-the-go LEGO fan?

Tags: sets

I keep a small box of electronic parts in the car, for times when I get an idea I want to try out, or have a quick gizmo that I need to solve a problem.  I also have a box of mechanical parts, like strings and pulleys and weights, that I'll use sometimes.  When I hang out with my engineering friends, we'll often come up with ideas that we can quickly build and test.  It seems that I should put together a similar set of LEGO parts.

I'm looking at a target volume about 3200 cm³ (200 cubic inches, 3.4 quarts), including space for organization.  No individual element should be larger than 140mm×230mm (17×23 studs).  The most important goal is versatility.  I'm mostly orienting this towards engineering tasks, but may also throw in a few minifigs for decorative builds.

The best idea I currently have is to use the [Creative Suitcase](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-creative-suitcase-set-10713), and augment it with parts from one of the smaller Technic kits that's almost entirely general-purpose Technic parts, like the [Compact Tracked Loader](https://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-compact-tracked-loader-set-42032).

It seems likely that people have built similar "on-the-go" kits, or have their "hotlist" of LEGO parts that are always at hand when prototyping.  Any thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have the parts in mind, but really just need a case.

I have used fishing tackle boxes and artist supply boxes, but the compartments were too narrow.

**Pros**: Versatile, cheap, stackable, configurable. 
You can use the removable compartments as parts trays during builds. You can find them in various colors at the major discount retailers in the U.S.

**Cons**: No handle. Not durable. If you drop or step on them, the hinges will crack.

**Dimensions**

- 13 3/8" L x 10 3/4" W x 2 1/2" H
- 34 cm x 27.3cm x 7.9cm

[image: Sterlite brand small container]

[Listing at the Sterlite website](http://www.sterilite.com/SelectProduct.html?id=831&ProductCategory=274&section=1)